# How to store the id returned, into others tables?

Tags: postgresql

I want to store the id returned from the table Soggetto into the others 2 tables (Tipologia > column soggetto_id and Tipologia2 > column soggetto_id)

I have this CTE in postgresql.

```
WITH retid AS (
  INSERT INTO "Soggetto" (nome, cognome, "regSociale", "partIVA")
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
      RETURNING id
 ),
 t as (
  INSERT INTO "Tipologia" (privato, azienda)
      VALUES ($5, $6)
 ),
 t2 as (
  INSERT INTO "Tipologia2" (cliente, fornitore)
      VALUES ($7, $8)
 )
SELECT id
FROM retid;
```

Comment: the columns are id(increment),name(char),surname(char).

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify destination for "Soggetto".id in both referencing tables, like here:

```
with i as (
   INSERT INTO "Soggetto" (nome, cognome, "regSociale", "partIVA") 
   VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id
 )
 , e as (
   INSERT INTO "Tipologia"(soggetto_id,privato, azienda) select SELECT id, $5, $6
   FROM i
 )
 INSERT INTO "Tipologia2"(soggetto_id,cliente, fornitore) select SELECT id,$7, $8
   FROM i
```